# Prints out array when I didn't ask for it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't know why it is printing out an array. I used the same method for another checkbox and it doesn't print out an array.

This is the code for the view

```
 <%= f.label "Category: " %>
 <%= Category.all.each do |category| %>
 <%= check_box_tag "course[category_ids][]", category.id %>
 <%= category.cat_name %>
 <% end %>
```

and this is what it prints:

```
Programming [#<Category id: 1, cat_name: "Programming", created_at: "2017-05-25 02:25:24", updated_at: "2017-05-25 02:25:24">]
```

Is there a way to remove the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing `Programming [#<Category id: 1, cat_name: "Programming"...]` because you're  using `<%= ... %>` instead `<% ... %>`, that's why you're printing the result of `Category.all.each`.

You can remove the `=` in your `Category.all` and that'll be as you want it.

Also I'd recommend you to create that as a variable in your controller and then to pass it to the view.